# unable connect to the Apache-nifi with url

Tags: apache-nifi

I install nifi-1.16.2 in virtual machine
the virtual machine's ip is 192.168.1.115
my machine used to connect nifi can ping to 192.168.1.115

i change the nifi.properties

```
nifi.web.https.host=192.168.1.115
nifi.web.https.port=9102
```

and then I start the nifi with "sh nifi.sh start"

now My machine can use "telnet 192.168.1.115 9102",but I can't use browser to visit website with the url "192.168.1.115:9102/nifi"

Answer (score 0):

In `conf/bootstrap.conf` try to set to `run.as` variable your current OS user. This helps me to connect.

Example: `run.as=my_user_name`